# OFFSET Formula Modification

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how the offset formula (e.g. `=OFFSET($B$5,(ROW(A1)*n)-1,0)`) works. However, can you advise how to modify it to get 1st cell from column B (and then as I drag it down) first cell from C and then second cell from B and second cell from C, and so on?

Thanks

Comment: And so on what?

Comment: ....3rd cell from col B and then 3rd cell from column C, 4th cell from col B and then 4th cell from column C, and so on. There are not enough characters to write the same sentence 2000 times - sorry.

Comment: So you want an Offset formula that will give you... `B1 C1 A2 B2 B3 C3 B4 C4 ...`? Can you please clarify as I cannot see the pattern here, sorry!

Comment: @JustynaMK sorry, I have clarified it now. B1 C1, B2 C2, B3 C3...

Comment: Thanks West, I think I got it now. I'll post my solution in a minute.

Comment: @JustynaMK appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a mix of `OFFSET`, `MOD` and `ROUNDUP` functions to get an ever-changing mix of `rows` & `cols` parameters:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,ROUNDUP(ABS(ROW(A1)/2),0)-1,MOD(ROW(A2),2))
```

I included some random values in cells `B1:C6` to present the result in a clearer way:

[image]

Comment: @WestRay I needed an additional minute to re-read your post... and I just realized how invalid my response is! Adjusting it now for an exemplary range of `B1:C6`.

Comment: My values are in two columns B and C (between rows 1 - 2000). I have used your formula in A1 and dragged it all the way down. I get B1 in A1 (good), B2 in A2 (wrong), C1 in A3 (should be in A2) and then 0 values all the way. What I need is: A1=B1,A2=C1,A3=B2,A4=C2...and the same pattern all the way down.

Comment: Yeah I did realize that a little bit too late (facepalm)! It should be all good now (see adjusted post).

Comment: haha no worries at all! It worked a miracle! Thank you so much, you are my saviour! :D

Comment: I owe you two coffees now - it's the second time you helped me :)